# Найти координаты вектора зная новую магнитуду

Tags: математика, вектор

Дано: вектор `[2, 4, 6]` магнитуда равна `7.4833`
Нужно найти координаты этого же вектора, но при магнитуде, например, `10`
Помогите сообразить как всё это просчитать, если можно код на c/c++, java, js, python или просто в псевдокоде или без кода с объяснением как всё вынести и посчитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто каждую координату умножаете на `10/7.4833` - `[2.673, 5.345, 8.018]`.

Код для умножения двух чисел, думаю, написать несложно...